# Confused with DateTime format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have String like '**Wed Jan 22 13:30:52 UTC 2020**', need to convert this string To IST format using Sql Server.

I don't aware the about above format.

Comment: Yes, But i have confused with this 'Wed Jan 22 13:30:52 UTC 2020' format only

Comment: actually the above string ported from one csv to Table, here i need the date conversion.

Comment: Removed unwanted tags ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might help:

```
declare @date varchar(50) = 'Wed Jan 22 13:30:52 UTC 2020'

select CAST(SUBSTRING(@date, 5, CHARINDEX('UTC',@date,1)-6) + SUBSTRING(@date,CHARINDEX('UTC',@date,1)+3,100) AS DATETIME) AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time'
```

`AT TIME ZONE` works on SQL Server 2016 and later.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be any of the formats recognized internally by SQL Server:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

So, you will have to convert it yourself. Lets suppose that we have your sample date:

```
declare @date varchar(50) = 'Wed Jan 22 13:30:52 UTC 2020'
```

You can get the date parts using substring (supposing that every date uses exactly the same format):

```
select substring(@date, 1, 3) as day,
       substring(@date, 5, 3) as month,
       substring(@date, 9, 3) as year,
       substring(@date, 12, 2) as hour,
       substring(@date, 15, 2) as minute,
       substring(@date, 18, 2) as second,
       substring(@date, 25, 4) as utc
```

Now you only need to built a datetime value from those date parts :

```
select datetimefromparts(convert(int, substring(@date, 9, 3)) + 2000,
                         case substring(@date, 5, 3) when 'Jan' then 1
                                                     when 'Feb' then 2
                                                     ...     
                         end,
                         case substring(@date, 1, 3) when 'Mon' then 1
                                                     when 'Tue' then 2
                                                     when 'Wed' then 3
                                                     ...  
                         end,                        
                         convert(int, substring(@date, 12, 2)),
                         convert(int, substring(@date, 15, 2)),
                         convert(int, substring(@date, 18, 2)),
                         0)
```

Finally you can add `AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time'` to define your IST timezone.

```
select datetimefromparts(convert(int, substring(@date, 9, 3)) + 2000,
                         case substring(@date, 5, 3) when 'Jan' then 1
                                                     when 'Feb' then 2
                                                     ...     
                         end,
                         case substring(@date, 1, 3) when 'Mon' then 1
                                                     when 'Tue' then 2
                                                     when 'Wed' then 3
                                                     ...  
                         end,                        
                         convert(int, substring(@date, 12, 2)),
                         convert(int, substring(@date, 15, 2)),
                         convert(int, substring(@date, 18, 2)),
                         0)
       AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time'
```